# Exception doesnt display the message that a previously raised exception has

Tags: python, exception, raise

So i was trying to use `Exception as e:` but the variable e wouldnt display the message i previously assigned to it. Could you please help me?

```
SERVICE_CHARGE= 2
TICKET_PRICE = 10
tickets_remaining= 100

def calculate_price(number_of_tickets):
    return (number_of_tickets * TICKET_PRICE) + SERVICE_CHARGE

while tickets_remaining:
    print "There are {} tickets remaining".format(tickets_remaining)

users_name=raw_input("What's your name?  ")

try:
    number_of_tickets=int(input("{}, how many tickets would you like to buy?  ".format(users_name)))
    if number_of_tickets>tickets_remaining:
        raise Exception("Not enough tickets remaining")       
except Exception as err:
    print "Im sorry. {}. Please try again!".format(err)
```

Comment: not sure why some of the code was left out of the block. I would like to know about that too!

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you write Exception as e, e becomes an alias for the value stored in Exception, ie, e temporarily stores the value of Exception and then discards it(becomes undefined). You should use(you mention the variable e in your question but use err in your code):

```
except Exception:
    print "Im sorry. {}. Please try again!".format(err)
```